# jquery, jquery_ujs with jquery-ui-rails gem

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-ui

Since jquery is packaged with Rails 3.0, I'm using the jquery-ui-rails gem to get jquery-ui.

Looks like jquery_ujs is not packaged with Rails (or jquery-ui-rails). And I can't independently include jquery_ujs gem (there is no such gem, it is packaged with the jquery-rails gem ... which specifically states that I don't need this gem if I'm on Rails 3.0+).

I try to require jquery_ujs in my application.js but obviously it's not found.

So how do I get jquery_ujs?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're including the jquery-rails gem in your Gemfile, then jquery-ujs is already installed.  Simply make sure it's added to your application.js manifest like so:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery-ujs
```

And if you also have jquery-ui-rails, you can then add a manifest entry for that:

```
//= require jquery.ui.all
```

Comment: So I'm not including the jquery-rails gem in my Gemfile because Rails 3.0 includes jquery by default. Then I include the jquery-ui-rails gem for jquery-ui. I ended up downloading the jquery_ujs.js file and then requiring it in my application.js file. things work now, please let me know if I should explicitly include the jquery-rails gem for some reason.

Comment: @RingoBlancke: "because Rails 3.0 includes jquery by default" - No, it doesn't.  Not if you **remove** the `gem 'jquery-rails'` in your Gemfile that Rails had put there by default.  You should absolutely include that gem if you're using jquery, unless you want to install a specific version of the jquery.js and jquery-ujs.js files manually.

Comment: Rails 3.0.6 does not include `gem 'jquery-rails'` by default. And it's pointless anyways, as there is no manifest for javascript. The asset pipeline, which uses the manifests, was introduced in Rails 3.1. @RingoBlancke probably came up with the best solution.